# log MongoDB collection data from results node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i have this, and it's working perfect:

```
socialPosts.find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);

            db.close();
        });
```

it logs all the documents in the collection, like so:

```
    {
    _id: 60dcaf07539e5d7d2ebc5180,
    title: "my Second Post",
    description: 'my second post',
    socialLink: 'sociallink.com/sociallink'
  {
    _id: 60dcc2a250351a7efc5f0e46,
    title: 'hello',
    description: 'hello',
    socialLink: 'hello'
  }
```

however, i want to pass these values to the front end, so i want to access the `title`, `description`, etc, all from the front end, but ideally i would like to be able to log them first. So i tried `console.log(result.title)`, but it didn't work. Not sure how to do this. thanks

Comment: if the result is an array then you should access array elements first then reference properties. In your case would be result[n].title, where n can be 0 to result.length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one liner solution:

```
result.forEach(item => console.log(item.title));
```

Answer (score 0):

touching on `tnaluat` comment, i was able to use the what was mentioned and loop thru.

```
 socialPosts.find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                console.log(result[i].title)
            }


           
           res.render('media.ejs', {data: result})

            db.close();
        });
```

then on the front end, i access the `data` through a loop in ejs.